# Is it possible to create ICriteria/ICriterion from LINQ or HQL?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql, icriteria

I am creating a method that can create filter understood by NHibernate (by filter i mean a set of ICriteria object for example) from my abstract filter object.

```
public static IEnumerable<ICriterion> ToNhCriteria(this MyCriteria criteria)
{
   // T4 generated function
   // lots of result.Add(Expression.Or(Expression.Eq(),Expression.Eq)) expression trees - hard to generate
   // Is there a way to generate HQL/Linq query here istead?
}
```

then i want to do something like

```
session.CreateCriteria<Entity>().Add(myCriteria.ToNhCriteria())
```

to filter entities.
The problem is that using Expression. methods (Expression.Or etc) is quite tedious (the method is generated and i have multiple or statements that have to be joined into an expression somehow).
Is there a way to avoid using Expression.Or() and create ICrietrion / ICriteria using LINQ or HQL?

Comment: Are you using T4 at design time or runtime to generate ICriteria?  If at design time, what is stopping you from using T4 to generate HQL (or Linq) instead?

Comment: Yes I am using T4 in design time and as you suggested i could use HQL or Linq instead of ICriteria. The problem was caused by my lack of knowledge rather than by framework limitations.
Currently I am using ICriteria API though as it seems to be most readable for someone reading T4 and it works properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, did you check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684696/nhibernate-linq-and-multicriteria) question?  It shows going from Linq to NHibernate to a MultiCriteria (and on the way transforms a linq query to an ICriteria)

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. Why don't you use linq instead of criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not the best solution unless you want to do filtering on collection-side not on datbase-side using WHERE clauses.
Ayende suggests that ICriteria API is well suited for dynamic filter creation, the problem i had with multiple ORs has been tackled by using Restrictions.Disjunction()... that simplified a lot
At the time I asked the question I just didn't realize such things exist in NHibernate :)